# What does the -r option of Git log do?

Tags: git, git-log

The man page [git-log(1)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) says:

> -r
>   Show recursive diffs.

So we can put this question in another way:

**What is meant by *"recursive diffs"* in this context.**

After getting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56100407/11402257) from @phd, I did some tests that aim in the indicated direction:

If I execute the following commands in a current version of the Git source repository (recently cloned from https://github.com/git/git.git) with checked out `master` (currently pointing to commit `6a6c0f1`), they give identical output:

```
git log --name-only -m
git log --name-only -m -r
```

(For this to work, one might have to increase the `diff.renameLimit` to round about `3150`.) I tried this with Git versions 2.10.2 and 2.17.1 obtaining equal results.

In addition, the command

```
git log --name-only -m master~..master
```

outputs

```
commit 6a6c0f10a70a6eb101c213b09ae82a9cad252743
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Thu May 9 00:37:54 2019 +0900

    The eighth batch

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

Documentation/RelNotes/2.22.0.txt
```

from the last line of which one can see that this command looks into subdirectories even without `-r`.

Comment: Along similar lines, the `-m`, `-c`, and `--cc` options have their documentation in the diff doc text files whcih are included from both `git log` and `git show` documentation files. But the front-end `log` and `show` commands set the *default* values of these options quite differently. If you merely read the docs, you'll have the impression that `git log` will default to showing a combined diff for a merge, but in fact `git log` defaults to *not* showing *any* diff (`git show` defaults to a combined diff).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option comes from [`git diff-tree` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt--r) and in `git diff-tree` it really works; see this example:

```
$ git diff-tree master~ master
:100644 100644 a2be0e5e5959396fb85445cfff714d7b04a1231b 5d7a2a0a4fd6fbaf439aa08bb7f17052a65a5236 M  ANNOUNCE
:100644 100644 22e746900ab77a79b4cb6780f536a517771fe276 f2aae0e9c7c87226f4f5c06ca006f4d04ce79dc1 M  ChangeLog
:040000 040000 54ef4d981c00162085347031d31286d630258153 76d21516ed54422a8981a31a9a0bf47dc5e5af6f M  mimedecode

$ git diff-tree -r master~ master
:100644 100644 a2be0e5e5959396fb85445cfff714d7b04a1231b 5d7a2a0a4fd6fbaf439aa08bb7f17052a65a5236 M  ANNOUNCE
:100644 100644 22e746900ab77a79b4cb6780f536a517771fe276 f2aae0e9c7c87226f4f5c06ca006f4d04ce79dc1 M  ChangeLog
:100644 100644 4ca2f25d2d061dba16294d67ab8018ea00be2b37 ead1ab38493c7e5119d8204a8731747cc534647c M  mimedecode/mimedecode.py
```

The option is included in docs at [git-diff-tree.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt) and the file is included in [git-log.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a6c0f10a70a6eb101c213b09ae82a9cad252743/Documentation/git-log.txt#L110) via diff-options.txt.

I suspect the inclusion of the option in `git log` docs is an artifact of doc generation. At least I cannot make the option works for me in `git log`.

Comment: Thank you, @phd, for your fast and enlightening answer. Playing around with `git log -r` in the Git source repository, I could not see any effect of that option either. I supplemented this in the question.

Comment: In fact, this is a general problem with Git documentation (and Git commands): they share sources and therefore options can be supplied that wind up having no effect, and/or are documented that have no effect or—in some cases where the documentation factorization was unwise, though I think most of these have been fixed over time—are actually rejected by the command.

Comment: It has been removed from git-log documentation
https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cea104b2c0266d61fbce7e9ba485dc6d13c0c8f